# NHibernate: Manually handling collection of values reading using IStatelessSession

Tags: .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-collections, istatelesssession

During bulk load of entities into a database, I have a scenario where an incoming entity relies on an existing entity in the database in order to compute a value. This dependency itself has a collection of value types which is used to help compute this value. Since I am using `IStatelessSession`, this collection is ignored when the entity is loaded via the session. I'd like to handle the load of this collection manually but am having trouble finding guidance on how to do this.

Can anyone suggest the easiest way to query values into a collection manually?